# Does cross_validate in scikit-learn automatically fits and train the model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

```
# from the titanic dataset
X = df.drop(columns="survived")
y = df.survived
scoring = ['accuracy','precision','roc_auc','f1',]
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.linear_model import (LogisticRegression)
def model_LR(): #logstic Regression
    index = ["kfold-1","kfold-2","kfold-3","kfold-4","kfold-5"]
    s = model_selection.cross_validate(LogisticRegression(), X, y, scoring = scoring, cv = 5 )
    s = pd.DataFrame(data = s, index = index)
    display (s)
    print ("The mean scores for the above:\n", s.mean())

model_LR()

# OUTPUT :
    fit_time    score_time  test_accuracy   test_precision  test_roc_auc    test_f1
kfold-1 0.003998    0.006969    0.774809    0.711340    0.823673    0.700508
kfold-2 0.003990    0.005005    0.820611    0.778947    0.856481    0.758974
kfold-3 0.003003    0.003989    0.774809    0.715789    0.796667    0.697436
kfold-4 0.002992    0.003992    0.767176    0.709677    0.841852    0.683938
kfold-5 0.001994    0.003989    0.819923    0.819277    0.877081    0.743169
The mean scores for the above:
 fit_time          0.003195
score_time        0.004789
test_accuracy     0.791466
test_precision    0.747006
test_roc_auc      0.839151
test_f1           0.716805
dtype: float64
```

My Question:
In my code above, by calling on the cross_validate with LogisticsRegression, I get scores (such as roc_auc) as if the model has been fitted and trained.
I did not use any fit or train function.
Does that mean that cross_validate does that automatically?
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do not need to fit or train explicitly when using `cross_validate()`. Also see this example from the [SKLearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html):

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
cv_results = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3)
```

Just as in your case you can already get the results with no further steps, e.g.

```
cv_results['test_score']
```

gives this:

```
OUT: array([0.33150734, 0.08022311, 0.03531764])
```

Comment: I see, Thank you.